# How to create dynamic routes with Gatsby.js and SSR?

Tags: gatsby, server-side-rendering

I have a web app that was developed by Gatsby.js. There is a content folder including Markdown documents for creating the content of the app. We manage the content with this folder.

We have created our own CMS and we want to manage the blog sections of this app by using this CMS for creating Blog pages and a dynamic routing system. Now, we know to use Server Side Rendering, but how?

To sum up, we want to use a Hybrid system for rendering the pages. The main contents except blog pages will be rendered with Gatsby default routing system, the blog sections will be rendered by SSR. Also, we need to create a dynamic routing system on the blog sections for not to lose any points from SEO without building application.

Answer (score 0):

For custom routes there are a number of ways you can do this. You have to remember that Gatsby IS mixed model to begin with -- meaning it does both SSR rendering of 'static pages' AND it does dynamic routing once deployed and loaded in the client browser (it's using `reach` under the hood, I believe).

The trick is the naming conventions that Gatsby uses... (took me a awhile to decode the magic too). Here is my config for one of my Gatsby sites:

```js
   exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, actions }) => {
   const { createPage } = actions
   // Make the front page match everything client side.
   // Normally your paths should be a bit more judicious. 
   // console.log(page.path); 
   if (page.path === `/productPage/`) {
     page.matchPath = `/active-listings/:prodID`
     createPage(page)
   }
    
   if (page.path === `/tagsPage/`) {
       page.matchPath = `/tags/:tagType/:tagName`
       createPage(page)
     }
    }
    
    exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
      const { createPage } = actions;
      const pages = await graphql(`
        {
          <<REDACTED GRAPHQL>>
        }
      `);
    
      const blogTemplate = path.resolve("src/templates/blog.tsx");
      const productTemplate = path.resolve("src/templates/shopProduct.tsx");
    
      // Make the blog pages...
      pages.data.query.edges.forEach(edge => {
        createPage({
          path: `/blog/${edge.node.uid}`,
          component: blogTemplate,
          context: {
            uid: edge.node.uid,
          },
        })
      })
    
      // Make the shop pages...
      pages.data.query.edges.forEach(edge => {
        createPage({
          path: `/shop/${edge.node.uid}`,
          component: productTemplate,
          context: {
            uid: edge.node.uid,
          },
        })
      })
    }
```

Here, `onCreatePage` is a dynamic route - that is using regex and some some custom syntax sugar (e.g. `:prodId`) to build routes on the client-side -- this means that for my pages, when a user goes to "https://www.example.com/tags/ids/NewPages" `NewPages` is NOT SSR created. The template for that page was created, but the data that fills out the template is dropped into the template in real-time (at the time of the request). In this way, it's VERY handy to build MANY pages based on `ids` or `tags` or something `RESTful` -- then your product DB or whatever is backing the data can easily provide it.

NOTE: You need to research your own needs to understand if/how/does this have an impact to your SEO!

///

Where you see `exports.createPages` this is the SSR portion of Gatsby. This is, in my case. fetching a bunch of data at the time of SSR/compile, building all the graphQL nodes, then using the nodes to build pages -- these pages are prebuild and part of your SPA payload that initially gets delivered to the end-user (on first load). This makes it SUPER fast once it's loaded, it's pretty great for crawlers/SEO, but it has the side effect of taking a long time to compile (think linear time in most case -- the more nodes, pages you have the longer to do builds). If you have 100's/1000's, maybe even 10000's of pages you are building in this way, probably not a big deal. But, if you have a variable length product catalog, this can eat up a lot of build time -- which may also not be a concern for some people.

Dealers choice - pick your poison.

For my development and websites, I often use BOTH strategies. I SSR blog pages very often, and I dyanmically build/route product pages (which is what you are seeing below); in this way, if a product page updates, it doesn't require a new build and it's all data driven. Blog pages are more static and I tend to let those build at compile time (no good reason and I could have done it the other way, but I didn't want to expose my backend blog DB to my front-end, so building SSR hides it).

Have a look at the docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/